# How do you set up ubercart to filter/sort by price

Tags: 7, views, ubercart

I'm new to Ubercart and just set-up a simple shop (Using Drupal 7 and Ubercart 7.x-3). In the default uc_catalog (table) view you are able to sort by product title.

When going to format -> table settings, there is an option to allow the title field to be sortable, but there is no such option for price. Is there a solution to allow the products in the table to be sorted by price?

I've tried adding a price to the sort criteria but the sort filter doesn't work.

Any help or pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Solved: Simply just created my own view to take care of this

Answer (score 2):

Use [Ubercart advanced catalog](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_advanced_catalog). Very useful views. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... add custom filters on Ubercart catalog and provide taxonomy, products attributes (select) and CCK (option widget) support.
>
> Filters are fully configurable. Product display is fully configurable with Display suite and Node display.

Answer (score -1):

I use Drupal 7 and uc_catalog is not upgraded for this edition. So, you can also use a view and sort by price, reference, title, etc... everything you want.